# Using a common test function with chai that fails the test run

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai

I have a problem with my test.

I want this behaviour:

```
let chai = require('chai');
let expect = chai.expect;
describe('something', function() {
    it('fails', function() {
        expect([1,2,3].length).to.be.equal(4);
    });
});
```

This test fails.

Now I have common logic, so I want to have some common parts in a different function. For this I wrote something like:

```
let chai = require('chai');
let expect = chai.expect;
describe('something', function() {
    it('fail please', function() {
        check_fail([1,2,3]);
    });
});

let check_fail = async function(body){
    expect(body.length).to.be.equal(4);
}
```

This test will fail because check_fail is an asynchronous function. But I need it to be async because in the function I use awaits. How can this test fail and not pass?

Comment: you can do async test. Just add async at the beginning of the test definition, and use await when calling check_fail. That should make the test fail

Answer (score 0):

It should be simple like in

```
describe('something', function() {
    it('fail please', async function() { // => add async
        await check_fail([1,2,3]); // => add await
    });
});

let check_fail = async function(body){
    expect(body.length).to.be.equal(4);
}
```

Hope it helps